# How to get the value from List of Map values in java and handle when it is not present

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I want iterate a list of map and check if the code is "**approved**" then add the "**id**" and "**date**" into another **map**. And I've scenario sometime code won't come as part my list of map (for example **Record 1** - I've the **code** for second element only, I've only **id** and **date** in my first element where as **Record -2** will have "**code**" in all the elements)

This is my code

```
List<Map<String, Object>> prodIds = ((List<Map<String, Object>>) myIds.get("result"));
```

**//This prodIds returns below in my java code:**

**Record 1:**

```
[{id=[14766724], Date=[1999-01-01]}, {id=[49295837], code=[approved], Date=[2003-04-01]}]
```

**Record 2:**

```
[{id=[58761474621], code=[approved], Date=[2017-09-30]}, {id=[3368781], code=[Cancelled], Date=[2014-01-01]}, {id=[48843224], code=[Cancelled], Date=[2009-01-01]}]
```

**Java Code**

```
List<Map<String, Object>> prodIds = ((List<Map<String, Object>>) myIds.get("result"));
System.out.println("prodIds : " +prodIds ); //  [{id=[14766724], Date=[1999-01-01]}, {id=[49295837], code=[approved], Date=[2003-04-01]}]

Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map<String, Object> map : prodIds) { 
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) { 
            String key = entry.getKey();
            System.out.println("Key : " +key);

            String value = (String) entry.getValue();
             System.out.println(" Value : " +value);
        }
    }
```

I'm having difficult here to add the key as "**id**" and value as "**Date**" in my **newMap** and I want to add the "**id**" and "**date**" for the code value "**approved**"

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You just need a simple null and empty check

```
for (Map<String, Object> s : prodIds) { 

   List<String> status = (List<String>) s.get("code");

      if(status!=null && !status.isEmpty()) {

         System.out.println("status value: " +status.get(0));
      }else {
        //some default value or do something 

       }

 }
```

Comment: I'm not able to use like this - List<String> status = (String) ((List) s.get("code")); I'm getting compilation error stating that Cannot cast from List to String. Type mismatch: cannot covert from String to List<String>

Comment: Thanks @Deadpool but this scenario is failing [{id=[147625], Date=[1999-01-01]}, {id=[492956837], code=[approved], Date=[2003-04-01]}]. I'm always getting null for s.get("code") because "code" is in index 1 I guess - if code is available in index 0 then the above logic work I guess. I mean something like this [{id=[147625], code=[approved], Date=[1999-01-01]}, {id=[492956837], Date=[2003-04-01]}]

Answer (score 0):

This should find all items that are approved and output the date (assuming your code values are a string):

```
prodIds.stream()
        .filter(m -> m.get("code") != null && m.get("code").equals("approved"))
        .map(m -> m.get("Date"))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I tried this approach but nothing is printing :(

Comment: It worked in my test, so you might have some case sensitivity issues.  if  "approved" is actually an enum, you'll need to correct.

Comment: Hi Ryan - I updated my post, I'm looking id and date in a new map if the code is approved. Can you please help me with this?